# How can I leverage the built-in Maps app in Windows 8 to provide directions for my app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I want to have maps and directions for my Windows Store app, but don't want to have to write and maintain that code.

Is there a way to leverage the built-in Maps app in Windows 8 (and Windows RT) to provide that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Store apps support [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx), which allows apps to register to be available for activation when a url with the matching protocol schema is clicked or tapped.

The Maps app that comes pre-loaded with Windows 8 and Windows RT supports protocol activation via the bingmaps: schema, which is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx).

Basically, in your app, you construct a hyperlink whose href starts with "bingmaps:" and, optionally, includes the desired query arguments. In my case, I ended up creating a URL like so:

```
if (item.latlong) {
    element.querySelector("article .item-directions").href = "bingmaps:?where=" 
    + item.address + ", " + item.city + ", " + item.state;
}
```

and then use that for the href of a hyperlink in my HTML/JS Windows Store app. When the user clicks the hyperlink, the Maps app launches, and centers on the provided address. The user can then get directions, print the map and directions, etc., and I don't need to write or maintain any of that code. Here's a pic of what it looks like in my app, Community Megaphone:

[image: Clicking the Get Directions link opens the Maps app]

Notice how having the app in snapped view lets me see both the event information, and the Maps app, simultaneously.

This is a handy way of quickly adding map and directions functionality to your app.

For more pics, and a video demo, check out [my blog post on protocol activation](http://devhammer.net/blog/w8wil-6-leverage-the-maps-app-for-location-based-features).

For more info on Windows Store app development, register for [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).